# Can't play video with VideoView for API<16 Error -2147483648

Tags: java, android, api, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm a newbie on Java and Android. I'm just planning a multimedia installation with a couple of smartphones. These are old, used smartphones with Android 2.3 (API 10) and higher (up to API 16) I'm currently testing different possibilities of streaming videos. The first method I tested is below uses a video-file which I put on a server which I access via WLAN:

```
...
   String vidAddress = "http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp4";
   startVideo(vidAddress);
...
   public void startVideo(String vidAddress){
        // starts a video - currently from internet
        vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        vidView.start();
    }
```

This works on ALL API-Levels I tested: API 10-16. My problem is, that I cannot expect, that WLAN is available at the places the multimedia installation will be shown. Therefore I have to store the videos on the smartphones. This I do on the internal storage.

If I replace:

```
   String vidAddress = "http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp4";
   startVideo(vidAddress);
```

by

```
   String vidAddress=getFilesDir()+"/"+vidFile;
   startVideo(vidAddress);
```

this works for API 16 but not for API 15 and older. In the Android Monitor of Android Studio I get the following error message:

```
07-20 14:50:23.260 23279-23279/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality D/***** Reality ONE: /data/data/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality/files/mundtest_005_2.mp4 file exists - length 1505189 bytes *****
07-20 14:50:23.260 23279-23279/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality E/MediaPlayer: Uri is  /data/data/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality/files/mundtest_005_2.mp4
07-20 14:50:23.280 23279-23290/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
07-20 14:50:23.290 23279-23279/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
07-20 14:50:23.290 23279-23279/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
```

The first line is a debugging printout I've implemented in startVideo to check that the file is accessible and the length is correct. I've also tried the method 'setVideoPath' instead 'setVideoURI' with the same result: working for API 16 and not working for older Versions.

I would be grateful for any help solving my problem. Thanks, Karin

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem, which means I found a workaround.

Apparently there is a problem (I guess due to my ignorance as newbie) with using video files from the internal storage in VideoView for API<16. Using **external storage** e.g.

```
import static android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES;
```

...

```
   private File filePath;
```

...

```
filePath = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_MOVIES)));
```

... then copying the video files into the directory filePath and retrieving them for playing the video

```
 vidAddress=String.valueOf(filePath)+"/"+vidFile;
 startVideo(vidAddress);
```

works with the method given above for all APIs I've tested (10,15,16) even without sd-card inserted.

The relevant messages on the Android Monitor in Android Studio ( e.g. for a Samsung GT S-5830i API 10) is

```
07-20 16:23:57.117 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality D/VideoView: onMeasure()
07-20 16:23:57.117 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality I/VideoView:     Setting size: 320x399
07-20 16:24:01.312 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality D/***** Reality ONE: /mnt/sdcard/Movies/mundtest_005_2.mp4 file exists - length 1505189 bytes *****
07-20 16:24:01.320 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality D/VideoView: onMeasure()
07-20 16:24:01.320 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality I/VideoView:     Setting size: 320x399
07-20 16:24:01.460 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality D/VideoView: onMeasure()
07-20 16:24:01.476 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality I/VideoView:     Setting size: 299x399
07-20 16:24:01.500 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
07-20 16:24:01.500 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality I/VideoView: start()
07-20 16:24:01.515 12548-12548/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality I/VideoView: start()
07-20 16:29:30.929 12548-12550/eu.karin_daum.daum.reality D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 359K, 48% free 3016K/5767K, external 697K/1036K, paused 3ms+3ms
```